# I need a non repeated random number generator

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a random number generator as below :

From 1 to 50

7 numbers

every number could be 2 digits or 1 digit
With spaces every number that generated.

for example : 1 31 22 35 3 45 23 47

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void main() {
  print(generateString());
}

String generateString() {
  var list = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
  return list.take(7).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with flutter or Dart, but the logic is fairly simple if you know the basics

1) Import random number generator
2) declare an array to store the numbers
3) write a for loop that executes 7 times
3.1) generate a random number
3.2) check if it exists in the array
3.2.1) if not, push to array
3.2.2) if exists, generate a new number

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to create a random number:

```
import 'dart:math';

...

int min = 1;
int max = 51;
Random rnd = Random();
int r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);

...
```

If you want to check if you already got the generated number, just add the result in a list and verify if that list contains the newly generated number via `myRandomNumberList.contains(r)? _generateRandom() : myRandomNumberList.add;`

It's just pseudo-code to show you one way to solve your problem.